# How do you resolve ODATA returning an open bracket of array and 'StatusCode could not be set' error

Tags: sql, .net, logging, odata

I am working on a .NET ODATA API that exposes data from SQL Views and is consumed by a 'Salesforce Connect' Connector.

If I execute a query with an ODATA filter applied my query works fine but when I test some filters i get the following output:

[image: ODATA Query returning open bracket Array]

Please note the 'open bracket response'. The response is 200 so I get an OK. But in my .NET logging I see the following error in my console:

```
fail: BARCO.ODataApi.Api.Web.AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      Request resulted in SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
       ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSetAsync(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectInlineAsync(Object graph, IEdmTypeReference expectedType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteObjectAsync(Object graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatterHelper.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, IEdmModel model, ODataVersion version, Uri baseAddress, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, HttpRequest request, IHeaderDictionary requestHeaders, IODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at BARCO.ODataApi.Api.Web.UnitOfWorkMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Github\BARCO\BarcoODataApi\BarcoODataApi\src\BARCO.ODataApi.Api\Web\UnitOfWorkMiddleWare.cs:line 46
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at BARCO.ODataApi.Api.Web.ClientConfigurationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Github\BARCO\BarcoODataApi\BarcoODataApi\src\BARCO.ODataApi.Api\Web\ClientConfigurationMiddleware.cs:line 66
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at BARCO.ODataApi.Api.Web.AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Github\BARCO\BarcoODataApi\BarcoODataApi\src\BARCO.ODataApi.Api\Web\AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 37
      ClientConnectionId:6b3c22ec-a535-4e66-99df-0cf41053a3f9
      Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMFRFUHVRJMQ", Request id "0HMFRFUHVRJMQ:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
         at BARCO.ODataApi.Api.Web.AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.SetResponseExceptionStatusCode(HttpContext context, Exception exception) in C:\Github\BARCO\BarcoODataApi\BarcoODataApi\src\BARCO.ODataApi.Api\Web\AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 101
         at BARCO.ODataApi.Api.Web.AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Github\BARCO\BarcoODataApi\BarcoODataApi\src\BARCO.ODataApi.Api\Web\AppExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Is there a way to provide more detailed logging so I can understand what exactly is going wrong in my application or where the error is? Since receiving a response of "value":"[" is really weird and I have never seen this kind of response. I searched online already but there does not seem to be any questions out there with the same issue concerning this response.

One of my first questions i posted so please let me know if there is a need for additional information on my question.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Salesforce Connect Backend Query translation:

```sql
SELECT TOP(@__TypedProperty_2) ...
FROM   ... AS [v]
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN ( @__TypedProperty_0 LIKE N'' )
               OR ( Charindex(@__TypedProperty_0, [v].[assetid]) > 0 ) THEN
         Cast(1 AS BIT)
         ELSE Cast(0 AS BIT)
       END = @__TypedProperty_1
ORDER  BY ...
```

Comment: Post exceptions and code as *text*, not images. Images can't be googled, copied, compiled or tested. It's not even clear what stack is used - is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Which version are you using?

Comment: With ASP.NET Core OData, when a response is cut in the middle like this it means an error occurred while loading or serializing the data. For example, trying to return a `null` value in a non-nullable property (eg a long) will cause errors. In .NET 6 though, nullable reference types are enabled by default and ASP.NET Core OData considers a `string` property to be non-nullable. Trying to return a `null` for a `string` property would violate the metadata, so the OData middleware throws

Comment: That screenshot seems to show a timeout exception though. You didn't post any code so it's hard to guess what's wrong. Perhaps the query code is inefficient. Perhaps the query is trying to query data without indexing. Perhaps it's trying to load too much data without paging.

Comment: This application is ASP.NET CORE and .NET 6 is used.

Comment: I understand your comments and appreciate the feedback! I can post some screenshots of the code if that would enhance my question but I think indeed that the Timeout might be the issue here. Is there a way to extend this Timeout in ASP.NET Core when querying the SQL database?

Comment: That's why you should post the exception as text, and post your actual code. Why would any query returning a single object time out? There's a serious bug in your code - either the code causes blocking at the database level, or you're trying to return 100K rows without paging.

Comment: Problems like this is why OData restricts the number of results by default. Did you disable the restrictions perhaps? Without restrictions, a badly written client could crash a server by requesting an entire table at once. OData didn't have such restrictions when it was first released, which resulted in *huge* problems and prevented adoption.

Comment: Your real problem has little to do with OData. Your query is timing out. To answer such problems, the code, query, table schema (including indexes) and execution plan are needed. Perhaps the query is too complex, or tries to retrieve to much data. Perhaps some other part of the code is using long-lived transactions that block queries for a long time. Perhaps the query is trying to filter on unindexed fields, which requires scanning all rows and locking the entire table.

Comment: Perhaps the query is using filters that require a full table scan. While `col LIKE 'abc%'` can use indexes, `LIKE '%abc'` or `LIKE '%abc%'` can't. `LIKE 'abc%'` can be translated to `col >='abc' AND col<='abd'`, a range search that can be accelerated by indexes. Looking in the middle or end of a string though *must* process every row in a table.

Comment: Your last comment is exactly what happens, If i translate my query in SQL I see that the query that the Salesforce Connector is using is a complex and rather weird query for a simple operation (as seen in the url). Please check my edited Question

Comment: That's why you should post your code and exception *as text*. Not images. That's not a simple operation anyway, it's the worst possible query. It *has* to scan the entire table. Don't use `contains`. It doesn't matter if it's translated to `assetId LIKE '%abc%'` or `CHARINDEX('abc',assetId)>0`, it still has to scan every row

Comment: I will Edit the question and post the error as text.
Next to that I have no impact on the query that is being fired to SQL. It is Salesforce Connect who calls external objects and my application serves as a Middleware API that passes through these objects & executes the queries, initiated by Salesforce Connect. So I have no impact on that sadly enough.

Comment: SalesForce doesn't force you to use `contains`. Their developers know the pitfalls of bad queries very well. Either someone wrote code that uses `contains` or someone created a UI search form that searches using `contains` instead of `equals` or `startswith`. What you posted in that image looks like a full ID - why is `contains` used in this case instead of `equals`?